# Determine if a field is a field of fractions

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

Let $R$ be a ring, let $K$ be a field, containing $R$ as a subring. Suppose that, for every $x\in K$, $x\neq 0$, either $x$ is in $R$ or $x^{-1}$ is in $R$. Can I conclude that $K$ is the field of fractions of $R$?

My thoughts: I define the field of fractions of $R$ in $K$ as $F(R):=\{r\cdot s^{-1}: r,s\in R, s\neq 0\}$. Then obviously $F(R)\subseteq K$. Conversely, let $x\in K$. If $x=0$ then $x$ is in $R$, and in $F(R)$. So suppose $x\neq 0$. By hypothesis, $x$ is in $R$ or the inverse of $x$ is in $R$. If $x\in R$, then $x=x\cdot 1^{-1}\in F(R)$. If $x^{-1}\in R$, then $x=1\cdot (x^{-1})^{-1}\in F(R)$

Comment: Do you know the definition of "field of fractions"? What are your thoughts about this question?

Answer (score 1):

Your thoughts are correct and well argued. If this is for a homework assignment I would also add in the answer to the question: right now you give the reasoning for the answer, but not the answer itself.